# How can i simplify this code by eliminating loop

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I have to Make each word's first letter capital using `vb.net`. for that i am using the following code. **it gives the correct result for me.** Let me know is their any simplest method for doing the same? following is the code i used:

```
    Dim input As String = "something anything nothing"
    Dim array() As String = input.Split(" ")
    Dim output As String = ""
    For i As Integer = 0 To array.Length - 1
        Dim temp() As Char = array(i).ToCharArray
        output &= Char.ToUpper(temp(0)) & array(i).ToString.Substring(1) & " "
    Next
    MsgBox(output)
```

Output will be

**Something Anything Nothing**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following is one of the simplest method for doing this: You can also try `LINQ`, `Regex`  etc to simplify your code:

```
 Dim input As String = "something anything nothing"
 Dim output As String = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(input)
 MsgBox(output)
```

You need to import `Imports System.Globalization` to work this code